# Routing to Display html file in laravel blade file using angularjs ng-view method using laravel-8

Tags: angularjs, laravel-8

how to set routing in angularjs controller and laravel routing to show html page under the angularjs component ---ng-view---.

can any one know how to display html file under ng-view in laravel-8

joblist.html file

```
<div class="card card-primary">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">Job</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <a class="btn btn-success mb-2 float-right" href="/jobform" role="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            Add Job</a>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
            <thead class="text-center dark-primary">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Id</th>
                    <th scope="col">Job Title</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width:50%">Description</th>
                    <th scope="col">Vacancies</th>
                    <th scope="col">UPDATE</th>
                    <th scope="col">DELETE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr ng-repeat="x in jobs">
                    <td>@{{ x.Job_id }}</td>
                    <td>@{{ x.Title }}</td>
                    <td>@{{ x.Description }}</td>
                    <td>@{{ x.No_of_vacancies }}</td>

                    <td class="text-center"><a ng-click="edit(x)"  class="btn btn-outline-primary" role="button"><i
                                class="fas fa-edit text-center"></i></a></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><a ng-click="delete(x)" class="btn btn-outline-danger" role="button"><i
                                class="fas fa-trash text-center"></i></a></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/jobangular',function(){
    return view('jobpagedisplay');
});
```

jobpagedisplay.blade.php file

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>add</title>

        <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
        <!-- Theme style -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
    </head>

    <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini" ng-app="job" ng-controller="jobController">

 <div ng-view>
</div>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script>
            var job = angular.module('job', ['ngRoute']);

            job.controller("jobController", function($scope, $http) {
                        $scope.init = function() {
                            $http.get('/joblist').then(function(data) {
                                $scope.jobs = data.data[0];
                            });
                        }

                        $scope.init()



                        $scope.delete = function(x) {
                            if (!confirm('Are yuo sure?')) return;

                            $http.post('job/delete', x).then(function(response) {
                                $scope.init()
                            })

                        }

                        job.config(function($routeProvider) {
                            $routeProvider
                                .when("/jobangular", {
                                    templateUrl: "joblist.html",
                                    controller: "jobController"
                                });


                        });
                    });
        </script>



    </body>

    </html>
@endsection
```

.html file is not showing in the ng-view div.
using laravel-8,
angular with cdn,
i write the script tag under the blade file.
how can i solve this